# Android allow multiple classes to listen to one class

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

let's assume that we are downloading a file in two different fragments at the same time using firebase storage, we can simplly check if we have a current active download task then attach a listener to the task and check the progress as well as get notified when the download is over, all well right? not really, the problem here is that the download listener will get triggered twice, once in screen 1 and then in screen 2, for example the user will get notified that the download has completed twice.

After some time thinking I came up with an idea to create a class that manages the downloads, each file that is currently being downloaded has one instance of the DownloadManager class, if two screens download the same file then there will be only one DownloadManager class for that file, the downloadManager class will listen to the download and notify the other classes of any progress occurring with the file download.

My question here is how can I let multiple classes listen to one class? I tried to create a method that receives a lambda then use the lambda to trigger than changes in the other class

```
var progressListener:()->Unit = {}

fun addProgressListener(progress: () -> Unit){
     progressListener = progress
}
```

when we create an instance of the class we just call "addProgressListener" and send the lambda

```
// the current file that is being downloaded by firebase storage
downloadTask.addOnProgressListener {
     progressListener()
}
```

but what if I had 10 other classes listening to the same file? if I call addProgressListener I will stop the previous class from listening.
I could save the lambda in an array list or hashMap but is that really efficient? How can create my own listeners and allow multiple classe to listen to one class? thank you.

Comment: have you heard of the observer pattern? This might be what you are looking for

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it, I will google it, if you have any useful links can you put them in a comment? thank you :)

Comment: I will post an answer, explaining the pattern with your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could save the lambda in an array list or hashMap but is that really efficient?

Your idea isn't so bad. But instead of having a lambda with a method, just create an interface with a method to be called on progress update:

```
interface ProgresListener {
    fun onProgressUpdate()
}
```

Every fragment which should listen to the DownloadManager first needs to implement this interface:

```
class SomeFragment : ProgresListener, Fragment() {


    override fun onProgressUpdate() {
        // do your individual reaction to progress update here
    }
}
```

The very nice thing about interfaces is that you can implement it individually in every class.

Next thing you want to do is add a list in your Downloadmanager which can store ProgressListeners. You also create methods to add and remove a listener:

```
class DownloadManager {

var observers: MutableList<ProgresListener> = mutableListOf()


fun subscribe(observer: ProgresListener) {
    observers.add(observer)
}

fun unsubscribe(observer: ProgresListener) {
    observers.remove(observer)
}
```

Once you want to inform your listeners (observer) about a progress update, iterate over the list and call the `onProgressUpdate()` method on every object in the list:

```
observers.forEach {
    it.onProgressUpdate()
}
```

In your last step, your fragments need to subscribe to the DownloadManager. Subscribing simple means adding a reference to the list in your DownloadManager. Add this in your `onCreate()` method of each fragment, or whenever you want to start to listen to progress updates:
`downloadManagerObj.subscribe(this)`

This pattern is called [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Its a very common pattern to solve the problem of many classes listening to updates of one single class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! but I have a question, what happens if you the fragment gets destroyed and you don't unsubscribe it from our list? I mean what if I wanted to subscribe an Item from a list (if I want to create a downloads list) items don't have a "onDestroy" so I can't unsubscribe them

Comment: So you have a recycler view and in every item of your view you want to update the progress?

Comment: no I mean I destroy the items in the view while they are still subscribed

Comment: yes I see that problem, but what kind of "items" do you mean?  Do you mean items inside a recycler view?

Comment: Yes, let's say that I have a recycler view in screen 2 which contains items that are observing our downloadManager, then when I press back screen2 will be destroyed along with the recycler view and the items inside of it.

Comment: you could either do a null check and remove observers with no reference when you call the `onProgressUpdated()` method. Or you add a public method in your item class that unsubscribes from the list. Your fragment which holds the list of items can then call this method on every item in the list in `onDestroy()`

Comment: But in your use case, maybe take a close look a [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxavcpomb7AIVF853Ch3obwmYEAAYASAAEgJLrPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata). Both are classes from android that are lifecycle aware and implement the observer pattern. You might have to restructure and refactor your code for this, but its a clean way and supported by android

Comment: I think it is much preferable to do a null checking rather than having to go through all of the items in the list, either way, thank you for the help!